# How to hide a boolean type for the deleted property in my form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a Symfony 4 entity that includes a boolean property for "deleted".  In my repository, I'm only returning entities that aren't marked as deleted.  When a user edits an entity and the form displays, there is a checkbox for "deleted" that I'd like to hide.

I tried doing this by changing the field type to HiddenType like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('logo')
        ->add('deleted', HiddenType::class)
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Create',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'],
        ]);

}
```

But when I submit the form, I get this error:
Expected argument of type "boolean", "NULL" given.

Any ideas on how to properly hide this field the symfony way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to include this hidden field in you form, but the fields are, by default, required.

See here :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required

If you set required to false, this may solve the issue.

If there's no value for deleted or it's set to null, you can set it by default to false like this :

```
$builder->add('deleted', HiddenType::class, [
    'empty_data' => false
]);
```